# In jasmine junitreport how can i add the different class name for each spec

Tags: node.js, jasmine

Im using jasmine test framework to test my node methods.Using jasmine junitreport reporter i'm getting test report as xml format.But in this xml all spec class have same name i want to change this class name.How can i do this..

Test cases

```
 describe('Test cases', function(){
 it('test1',function(){
  expect(true).toEqual(true);
 });
 it('test2',function(){
  expect(true).toEqual(true);
 });    
 });
```

Result

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <testsuites>
 <testsuite name="Test cases" timestamp="2013-10-25T10:24:25">
   <testcase classname="Test cases " name="test1" time="0.002"></testcase>
   <testcase classname="Test cases " name="test2" time="0"></testcase>
 </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
```

In this above report how can i add seperate class name for each testcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the node jasmine-reporters package
then you can change the code to output different class names. 
The line in the `node_modules\jasmine-reporters\src\jasmine.junit_reporter.js` file that outputs the test name is

```
spec.output = '<testcase classname="' + this.getFullName(spec.suite) +
              '" name="' + escapeInvalidXmlChars(spec.description) + 
              '" time="' + spec.duration + '">';`
```

You can change the `this.getFullName(spec.suite)` to output whatever names you want.